# Leaflet custom map (prod. with MapTiler) not shown in version 0.7.3

Tags: leaflet

My custom map which has been produced by using MapTiler 0-5 levels displays well
on leaflet 0.6.4 but is not shown on version 0.7.3. Sorry, but I'm really new in using leaflet and maps. I've googled and checked the documentation on leaflet.com but haven't got any clue of a solution. Please help.

This is a [demo using 0.6.4 and html already prepared for 0.7.3](http://www.meteosoft.ch/m.html).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry folks, I've just found my solution after googling again with other search
criteria. So I've found thread #2776 from Jakoboud pointing me to a possible solution. This does the trick -> continuousWorld: true and my map shows up.

Here's another question: how can I keep this map centered in browser window if the shown map part is smaller in width/height than browser window? map.setMaxBounds() doesn't work, it's bouncing the small map endlessly.

Comment: Another question should be posted as a new question, nobody except weirdos like me read everything, and answering on an answer is not really handy for other users if they are looking for the same solution. I'de post a new question if i was you.